# Variable-length arguments function

Tags: python

I need to know the role of for loop in this as i can print x directly without loop 
I try to print x without loop i get same answer but not all numbers in same line

```
def print_info(arg, *x):
    print ("Output is: ")
    print arg
    for var in x:
        print var
    return;

print_info(10)
print_info(70, 60, 50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*x` is the tuple of arguments so when you use for-statement, you print each argument in this tuple element-by-element. But when you use `print(x)`, you print the whole tuple:

```
def print_info(arg, *x):
    print("Output is: ")
    print(arg)
    for var in x:
        print(var)

print_info(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Will print:

> ```
> Output is: 
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> ```

And this code:

```
def print_info2(arg, *x):
    print("Output is: ")
    print(arg)
    print(x)

print_info2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Will print:

> ```
> Output is: 
> 1
> (2, 3, 4, 5)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

the parameter `*x` (or more generally `*args`) is used to send a non-keyworded variable length argument list to the function.

This means that all the values after your first parameter `arg` is sent as list, and therefore you can iterate through it

in your example:

```
print_info(10)
# 10 is arg
# () is *x (basically it is an empty list)

print_info(70, 60, 50)
# 70 is arg
# (60, 50) is *x
```

The why you are getting two different results printing x without for loop is because you are printing x as list, and not iterating through it,

Using print for each element you add a "\n" for every element printed by default

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join all values and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to convert all of them to `str`.

**Code:**

```
def print_info(arg, *x):
    print " ".join(map(str, (arg,) + x))

print_info(10)
print_info(70, 60, 50)
```

**Output:**

```
10
70 60 50
```

Comment: why convert them to str?

Comment: @MoatazMahmoud, cause `join()` expect str value.